# Trapezoid Rule in python without numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

While im trying to find the total area of a function lnx, in the end i'm always getting zero for any input value of N besides 1. It only works when i choose N=1. When i add them up in manual it looks fine. Ive just started to work on python so i dont know what is wrong with my code.

```
import math
from math import log



N=int(input(" Number of partitions: "))
dx=(3-2)//N
area=0
for i in range(1,N+1):
    area += 0.5*((((math.log(i)))+math.log(i+1)))*(dx)
    break
print (area)
```

Comment: dx will always be 0 because you use integer division (//),except when N is 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you have 2 division operators. 
You used `//`, that is the **real floor division** operator (that returns floor value for both integer and floating point arguments). In your code, you have to use `/`, that returns a float value if one of the arguments is a float.

So, you have to write:

```
dx=(3-2)/N
```